# Getting values from cursor

Tags: java, android, sqlite, cursor

I have a really weird problem.

When I want to get the values from the cursor I use the following code.

```
public Customers getCustomerByCursor(Cursor cursor){
    Customers customer=new Customers();
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    customer.setID(cursor,getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(CustomersDB.COLUMN_ID)));
    customer.setAccount_name(cursor,getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CustomersDB.COLUMN_ACCOUNTNAME)));
    customer.setName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CustomersDB.COLUMN_NAME)));
    customer.setLastname(cursor,getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CustomersDB.COLUMN_LASTNAME)));
    customer.setAddress(cursor,getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CustomersDB.COLUMN_ADDRESS)));
    customer.setPhone(cursor,getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CustomersDB.COLUMN_PHONE)));
    customer.setIsactive(true); customer.setPassword(cursor,getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CustomersDB.COLUMN_PASSWORD)));
    return customer;
}
```

But the values do not enter into the object correctly or do not enter at all.

For example, in the below code, 0 returned, that's not correct.

```
customer.setID(cursor,getInt(0)));
```

And in the rest lines not return any value. Can anyone please help?

Comment: Post your actual code. This code does not even compile.

Comment: Did you check if the cursor is not null and the cursor does contain some value?

Comment: And, can you please share the `setID` function?

Answer (score 0):

`customer.setID(cursor,getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(CustomersDB.COLUMN_ID)));`

Should very likely be `customer.setID(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(CustomersDB.COLUMN_ID)));`

i.e. the `getInt` is a public method of a Cursor object, so to invoke on a Cursor you code the name of the cursor object followed by a full stop which is then followed by the getInt method e.g.

```
cursor.getInt(column_offset_as_an_integer) // e.g. cursor.getColumnIndex(column_name_as_a_string) will return the column offset as an integer (if found)
```

You should also not assume that the Cursor method `moveToFirst` always moves to the first row, as if there are no rows, it cannot move to the first row. You should always check the returned value, a boolean, which will be true if the move can be made, if not then it will be false.

As such, it would appear that your code should be :-

```
public Customers getCustomerByCursor(Cursor cursor){

    Customers customer=new Customers();
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        customer.setID(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(CustomersDB.COLUMN_ID)));
        customer.setAccount_name(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CustomersDB.COLUMN_ACCOUNTNAME)));
        customer.setName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CustomersDB.COLUMN_NAME)));
        customer.setLastname(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CustomersDB.COLUMN_LASTNAME)));
        customer.setAddress(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CustomersDB.COLUMN_ADDRESS)));
        customer.setPhone(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CustomersDB.COLUMN_PHONE)));
        customer.setIsactive(true);
        customer.setPassword(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CustomersDB.COLUMN_PASSWORD)));
    }
    return customer;
}
```

- Noting that in the case that the Cursor contains no rows, that the returned Customers object will not have any of the values set. You would likely check the returned Customers object to check for such an occurrence.